# Box Javascript Upload

Tags: file-upload, cross-domain, box-api

I am trying to upload files directly to Box.com using the BOX API 2.0 using Javascript. The request will not go through because of cross-domain security limitations. Currently, for uploads, I am requesting a PHP script that makes a cURL request to Box but this is not ideal since the files get temporarily uploaded to my server first.

I found this post on how to get this done with Javascript:
http://developers.blog.box.com/2011/09/28/using-the-box-api-with-javascript/

Unfortunately it refers to the BOX 1.0 API.

Is there a way to directly communicate with BOX API 2.0 using just javascript? Any workout around for my upload issue?

Comment: AFAIK there's no reason the techniques mentioned in that article would not work with the V2 API.

Comment: If that is the case, how do you suppose that I send the Box Authorization header with the token and API key? I believe that in Box 2.0 you cannot send the tokens and API keys through the URL. Please correct me if I am wrong and provide me with an upload API URL format that allows me to pass in the authorization information.

Comment: You are correct that the tokens must be passed through the Authorization header in the V2 API.  Looking through the yql documentation it seems to suggest that setting headers should be possible, but it doesn't look trivial.  If I get a chance I'll try to mess around with it and see what I can accomplish.

Comment: Thank you, I'll be on the look out for your response.